# Why is Botulinum toxin the most potent poison known?

Tags: neuroscience, pharmacology, toxicology

Botulinum toxin (trade name Botox) inhibits acetylcholine release in neurons and causes botulism, an acute paralytic disease which leads to nerve degeneration and takes a long time to recover. I've read the statement that Botox is the most potent poison we know a few times now and was wondering *why exactly* it is. All sources I've found only claim *that* it is, without explanation.

Comment: do you want to know the mechanism? Or numbers for comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search for a [list of LD50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_lethal_dose) (median lethal dose; half of the people will die with that dosage) gave me 1 ng/kg for Botulinum toxin. This is pretty darn small amount, and in fact the smallest amount within that table.

Comment: True. Also look at the [potency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potency_%28pharmacology%29) page on Wikipedia

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the *why*, it doesn't explain the reason for the high toxicity.

Comment: @MadScientist I didn't know if OP wanted to know "why it is known for the most potent poision" or mechanism of Botox. I asked OP via comment, but with no answer so far.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, LD50 is a good criterion for a statement like this and I expect many of the sources where I've read it are probably referring to this. Though the question remains what exactly gives BT such a low LD50 - it's not the only neurotoxin out there, and some members of the BT family have much higher LD50's despite a very similar mechanism of action. I'm afraid that might be a question yet unanswered by science though.

Answer (score 4):

The [biochemical mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulinum_toxin#Biochemical_mechanism_of_toxicity) of BT is pretty well laid out at Wikipedia already. The toxin is likely very potent because (1) it is targeted to neurons; (2) neurons endocytose BT; and (3) the BT light chain's protease activity is able to cleave a wide range of SNARE-complex proteins which effectively disrupt the neurons ability to secrete monoamine neurotransmitters, and peptide hormones. Basically, the neurons are completely inhibited from transmitting nerve impulses.

Comment: Many poisons simply bind to and deactivate their target proteins. BT proteases can bind to, damage, and unbind to find other targets. Good answer.